# Setup APIgateway from Swagger | programmatically

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create multiple APIs in APIGateway using a **Swagger file.**

Right now, when I use the AWS console, I manually import the swagger file and then add the endpoints/authentication in every API created.

I want to complete the same task using **AWS Lambda (Node JS)**, so that i may:

1. Create APIs using Swagger
2. Add endpoints (custom server)
3. Add authorizer (cognito)

I looked into [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ImportExport.html) but was not able to understand it in a proper way. 
How to complete this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use `swagger`, I would say

- Write your APIs in `swagger` json format
- Parse it to add your `API gateway` extensions (endpoints/authorizer/role)
- Publish it

**Or**

- Create your API with the given `swagger` document
- Pass the `restapi id` to a `lambda` function
- Use `apigateway` SDK (e.g. [NodeJS SDK for APIGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html)) to get resources and methods for the restapi and add integrations to it.

But have you considered `AWS Cloudformation` scripts? In my current project, I have considered what you want to do but being no expert in `swagger` I chose `Cloudformation` over it. (also considered `AWS SAM` and `serverless`). It is a little repetitive but found much easier to write and understand. Here's an example of an endpoint in CFN yaml format -

```
ResourceUserActions:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
  DeletionPolicy: Delete
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
    ParentId: !Ref ResourceUser
    PathPart: "{action+}"
UserActionsMethod:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
Properties:
  RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
  ResourceId: !Ref ResourceUserActions
  HttpMethod: ANY
  AuthorizationType: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
  AuthorizerId: !Ref ApiAuthorizer
  Integration:
    Type: AWS_PROXY
    IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
    Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${HandlerFunction.Arn}/invocations
    Credentials: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRole.Arn
```

Type `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource` defines a resource, and `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` adds method, authorizer, integration type details to the resource. For more details, see [AWS CFN for APIGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-apigateway.html)

Comment: Actually, I've been provided with a swagger file. And my task is to automate the API Gateway setup using that swagger file.

Comment: added another option in the answer.

Comment: In this point "Create your API with the given swagger document", how to do this using Node JS or how to automate this step?
I am basically stuck at this point. I was not able to find the respective API

Comment: You will have to use `Cloudformation` to create restapi from swagger. Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html. It has an option to take OpenApi spec from S3. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-restapi-bodys3location.html